# Advanced search result is not coming in magento on home page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i added advanced search option on my home page by placing this code  in 
/app/design/frontend/default/hellowired/template/page/2columns-right.phtml

```
<div> 
<?php  echo
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml')->toHtml() 
?>
</div>
```

[image]

when press submit button then it giving me nothing. so **result are not showing...** please help

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are getting  the post url of the form as {{base-url}}/catalogsearch/advanced/result/

Comment: as per your answer i checked the action of form. that form is located in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/advanced/form.php
<form action=<?php echo $this->getSearchPostUrl() ?>>

Comment: sorry but form use get method
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSearchPostUrl() ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">

Comment: check the form post link http://www.plant-bulbs-direct.co.uk/index.php/ ..it is incorrect..should be http://www.plant-bulbs-direct.co.uk/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/

Comment: dude just go and change the action :)